# How to Disable export button when the page postbacks the button is in enable in asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

In my application Export button is there i need to export grid view data to excel in that i need to do two things

1. In my grid view have filter records functionality using Jquery Data table plugin while filtering records if there is no data to filter it occurs a message "No matching records found" that time i need to disable export button after enable this code i took in Jquery.
2. when I click edit button in grid view again i need to disable export button. Here when i click edit button it disabled that time page is postback again exceute jquery data table it shows enable only even when i click edit also

code for No matching records found to disable export button

```
$('#example').dataTable({
    "drawCallback": function( settings ) {
        var api = this.api(); 
        var dataLength = api.rows( {page:'current'} ).data().length;
        if (dataLength == 0) {      
            document.getElementById('<%= btnExport.ClientID %>').disabled = true;
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById('<%= btnExport.ClientID %>').disabled = false;
        }
    }
});
```

button for code

```
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="panl1" runat="server">
       <ContentTemplate>
          <asp:Panel ID="pnl1" runat="server">
      <asp:Button ID="btnExport" runat="server" OnClick="btnExport_Click" Text="Export" />                                      
          </asp:Panel>
     </ContentTemplate>
  </asp:UpdatePanel>   

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/g/mark.js(jquery.mark.min.js),datatables.mark.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/g/mark.js(jquery.mark.min.js)"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.13/features/mark.js/datatables.mark.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/datatables.mark.js/2.0.0/datatables.mark.min.css"></script>
```

Please tell me how to disable

Thank you.

Comment: Could you share the code for the button ?

Comment: Could you keep the button disabled, and enable it only when your condition satisfies in Jquery to enable it?

Comment: yes, but that is the in Jquery Data Table has found "No matching records found" for disable button. but I need to disable export button when i click edit in grid view

Comment: You could disable it in the render function

Comment: @Béranger, could you please tell me how can i do this

Comment: Wich library do you use exactly ? https://datatables.net ? Do you use editor ?

Comment: Can you please see i added my script source references